# Simple MFT base (that isn't a workbench)

Tags: workbench

I've made the plunge to buy a CNC'd MFT top, but it's just a sheet of MDF.

I don't currently have my shed set up to have any sort of proper workbench, so I'm thinking of making some sort of low base for it that I can use on top of my folding occasion table etc.

I've seen something like the UJK base, but it's a tad expensive

[image]

I have also seen some people use extruded aluminium:

[image]

However, I'm unsure which way to go and could do with some advice either way.

On one hand, a wooden base would be (potentially) to make myself - pocket-holing my way to an uneven mess. But on the other I do like the sound of the aluminium frame - I'm just not sure which profile to get... I have seen that I can get reasonably priced extrusion from [Ooznest](https://ooznest.co.uk/) and [aluminium-profile](https://www.aluminium-profile.co.uk/)

Again, this would have to be portable and storeable.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Torsion box? Pretty much the one and only requirement to make a good one is a flat surface to work on. You don't even have to stress about cutting all the elements to exact dimension, these are surprisingly tolerant of unequal pieces.

Comment: @Graphus I think I'm wanting something quick and easy to put together. The aluminium extrusion method would be an interesting project to whack together. My only questions for that one would be, which extrusion is the correct one? I've seen that there is a multiplpe stack of 20mm extrusion - I would want to an F clamp to slilde through.

Comment: My first question is: What is the worktop surface used for? You state it is not a workbench in the question but suggest it is in the body of your post. It doesn't matter much what the benchtop is made of if it does not sit on a stable base and determining what is stable depends upon what you will use it for.  Key considerations include how much weight and what kind of forces are applied when using it (clamping, planing, etc.). Placing a top on a portable folding leg base does not sound very sturdy.

Comment: *"I think I'm wanting something quick and easy to put together."* Are you a little woolly on what a torsion box is? Ain't nothin' easier to put together! And what you end up with is super stiff and flat (assuming it's made on a flat surface as I indicated).

Comment: What is a "MFT top"? We're not all up on the latest acronym soup...

Comment: I'm not sure if this "needs more focus" or if it's opinion-based, but it's so vague that it will be very hard to answer.

Comment: @FreeMan, Google mah man! MFTs are big over this side of the pond... apparently less so over there?

Comment: physicsboy, don't know if I was being really dense before but would it work to simply attach it to a lamination of plywood and call it done?

Comment: Voting to close just because I don't think there are any objectively correct answers here — any solution you pick will be fine as long as you like it. Don't worry about what you see on YouTube videos and such — think about what will work for *you* and try that. If it turns out not to work so well, you can adapt, and you'll have learned something.